# Jquery post only checked variables. How to do it right?

Tags: jquery, post, checkbox, checked

I have this HTML code:

```
<form name="allcats">
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat1' id='cat1' value='1'  /> AAAAAAA</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat2' id='cat2' value='2'  /> BBBBBB</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat3' id='cat3' value='3'  /> CCCCCC</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat4' id='cat4' value='4'  /> DDDDDDD</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat5' id='cat5' value='5'  /> EEEEEEEE</label></p>


<input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="12" />     <br />
<input name="catsadd" id="catsadd" type="button" value="Add catategories" onclick="check();"/>
</form>
```

And my jQuery code is:

```
function check(){

$.post('post__categories.php', { HERE MUST BE THE VARIABLES AND VALUES OF CHECKED checkboxes like ... cat1: allcats.cat1.valu, cat5: allcats.cat5.value},

function(output){
 $('#result').hide();
 $('#result').html(output).fadeIn("slow");

 });
 }
```

My goal is to send to post my checked variables and after that my PHP code will do its job.

But the construct must be like variable: `myform.variable.value`.

How do I get only the checked boxes via jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, give your form an ID so that it is easier to target:

```
<form name="allcats" id="allcats">
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat1' id='cat1' value='1'  /> AAAAAAA</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat2' id='cat2' value='2'  /> BBBBBB</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat3' id='cat3' value='3'  /> CCCCCC</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat4' id='cat4' value='4'  /> DDDDDDD</label></p>
<p class='catslist'><label><input type='checkbox' name='cat5' id='cat5' value='5'  /> EEEEEEEE</label></p>


<input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="12" />     <br />
<input name="catsadd" id="catsadd" type="button" value="Add catategories" onclick="check();"/>
</form>
```

Then, you need to serialize the form data in your request:

```
$.post('post__categories.php', { $("#allcats").serialize()});
```

Comment: but serialize()  make variables lik: a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4 But $.post needs a: 1, b: 2 ... 

Then what to do? I've tried your advice .. but still not working((

Comment: That is exactly the format you need it. You should be able to access cat1 for example using $_POST['cat1'] in your PHP script.

Comment: My PHP code is
`for ($c=0;  $c<=$catscount; $c++){
 if (isset($_POST['cat'.$c]))  {
$data['book_id'] = $_POST['book_id'];
$data['cat_id'] =   $_POST['cat'.$c];
if ($db->insert("Books_Cats_REL", $data)){ $done = "1";}
}
}`

Comment: This is a seperate problem. Your PHP script is starting the counter from 0 which is pointless. And it will also iterate above the maximum catX value. You should add var_dump($_POST); to this script, and take a close look at the structure of the incoming $_POST data. I have answered *this* question so you should mark it as answered as the PHP problem is a seperate issue.

Comment: $c=0 was old version sorry .. my right code $c=1. My PHP waits the variables to add them to Mysql. Whithout Jquery I can this do without problem. But now I use Jquery and my PHP waits variables like cat1: allcats.cat1.value .. Tell me what to do in this case when with serialize variables comes like cat1=1&cat2=2 .. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: It is done: `$.post('post__categories.php', {results: $("#allcats").serialize()}`  and my php code is `$data = explode("&", $_POST['results']); foreach($thedata as $new) { list($x, $y) = explode("=", $new); ${$x} = $y;}. Thank you.
`